# Can you apply a site template to a subsite of a Developer Site on Office 365 (SP2013)?

Tags: 2013, site-template, office-365, dev-site

For development testing I use the "Developer Site" site definition for my root web.  When I create a sub-site of this developer site I want to use a custom site template I have created.  However, when I attempt to do this, I get the following error:

> This web template requires that certain features be installed, activated, and licensed.  The following problems are blocking application of the template:
>
> ```
> Feature Description         Feature Scope    Feature ID                            Problem
> SearchDriveContent Feature  Site collection  592ccb4a-9304-49ab-aab1-66638198bb58  Not Activated
> ```

However, I looked through the site collection features of my dev site and of the site that was used when creating the site template and they had the same features that were activated.

It leads me to believe that creating a subsite on a development site using a site template is not possible, but I really hope that is not the case as we have an app that needs to be developed and tested against a specific site template.

Note that this is all on O365 / SharePoint Online using SP2013.

Note that I have tried to use Visual Studio to deploy to a non-dev site but I get the "sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site" error.  I have read that you can enable a hidden feature to allow for this (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2013/02/04/quot-sideloading-of-apps-is-not-enabled-on-this-site-quot.aspx) but you have to use PowerShell to enable the feature since it is hidden and Enable-SPFeature is not one of the PowerShell scripts available in O365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage you re features in office 365.

First first install the [SharePoint Online Management Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

In order to enable a feature in o365, you will need to make use of Client-side object model (CSOM). Once the SharePoint Online management Shell is installed, It installs Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell Module which you need to import in your scripts before you can use CSOM.

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)    
$clientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
```

Add the feature definition of the feature you are trying to activate to the Feature Collection in the SPSite/SPWeb (depending on the scope of the feature) object and execute the operation.

```
$site = $clientContext.Site;     
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "592ccb4a-9304-49ab-aab1-66638198bb58"     
$site.Features.Add($featureguid, $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None);      
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: That solution worked perfectly!  Thanks a lot for the response!!!

Comment: FWIW, I blogged a more full description of the problem and solution here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80809/can-you-apply-a-site-template-to-a-subsite-of-a-developer-site-on-office-365-sp